# openCL wrong result

Tags: opencl

Could somebody explain me why is it happen?
I tought it'd increment the value of my array.

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "OpenCL.lib")
#include <CL/cl.h>

const std::string source_str = R"(
__kernel void add(__global int* c) {

    int i = get_global_id(0);

    c[i]=c[i]+1;
})";

size_t source_size = source_str.length();
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret;
cl_context context;
cl_command_queue command_queue;
cl_mem a_mem_obj;
cl_program program;
cl_kernel kernel;
int* a;
#define SIZE 100

// ## You may add your own initialization routines here ##
void init() {
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 1;
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 2;

    // Create an OpenCL context
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 3;

    // Create a command queue
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 4;

    a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
        SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 6;

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
        (const char**)&source_str, (const size_t*)&source_size, &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 9;

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 10;

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "add", &ret);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 11;

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&a_mem_obj);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 13;
}

void KernelStart() {

    // Copy to the memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        SIZE * sizeof(int), a, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 7;

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t static global_item_size = SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t static local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
        &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 14;

    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        SIZE * sizeof(int), a, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 15;
}

int main() {
    a = new int[SIZE];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    init();
    KernelStart();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

result:

> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>
> -4913-54141111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: Add some prints before and after the two functions: init() and KernelStart();
So you can isolate the output of both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logging already shows you what's going on, albeit not particularly readably.

#### First Problem

Your program's output:

> -4913

The corresponding code:

```
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&a_mem_obj);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 13;
```

`-49` is `CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX`. Kernel arguments are numbered from 0, your kernel has 1 argument, so the only valid index is 0.

#### Second Problem

Your program's output:

> -5414

The code:

```
#define SIZE 100

…

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t static global_item_size = SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t static local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
        &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << ret << 14;
```

`-54` corresponds to `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`.

There are [3 possible reasons specified](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html):

> - `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` if local_work_size is specified and number of work-items specified by global_work_size is not evenly divisable by size of work-group given by local_work_size or does not match the work-group size specified for kernel using the `__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z)))` qualifier in program source.
> - `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` if local_work_size is specified and the total number of work-items in the work-group computed as `local_work_size[0] *... local_work_size[work_dim - 1]` is greater than the value specified by `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` in the table of OpenCL Device Queries for `clGetDeviceInfo`.
> - `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` if `local_work_size` is `NULL` and the `__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z)))` qualifier is used to declare the work-group size for kernel in the program source.

Your local size is 64, your global size is 100. This means you're running into the first condition: you'll need to make sure your global size is an integer multiple of the local size.